# How to access model nested attributes in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, nested-attributes

I have the following relations in my models:

- security_user.rb

> ```
> has_many :security_users_roles_to_users
> has_many :security_users_roles, through: :security_users_roles_to_users
> accepts_nested_attributes_for :security_users_roles
> ```

- security_users_roles_to_users.rb

> belongs_to :security_user
>   belongs_to :security_users_role

- security_users_roles.rb

> has_many :security_users_roles_to_users
>     has_many :security_users, through: :security_users_roles_to_users

The purpose is to create many-to-many relationship between users and roles models.

When a new user is created I want to set to him default role (for example user). So, in my security_users_controller.rb, in the *create* action I have:

```
@security_user = SecurityUser.new(params[:security_user])
@security_user.security_users_roles.role = 'user'
```

But I get the following error: *undefined method `role=' for ...*

Why I am not able to acces the attribute in the way above?

Note: I am not passing any information from the from for the user's role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `@security_user.security_users_roles` is an ActiveRecord association, so you can't set role on that.

Try something like

```
@security_user.security_users_roles_to_users.build(security_users_role: SecurityUsersRole.find_by_role('user'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the following error - You cannot call create unless the parent is saved app/controllers/security_users_controller.rb. Also, using build, it seems to making the trick but maybe I am not doing the right think. In my roles model, I should have a record 'user', so maybe I need to add record in the join table to mark that user is in this role?

Comment: Mxm, I am getting this error - Can't mass-assign protected attributes: security_users_role. Do you have any idea what is causing it?

Comment: Yep, you have to set `attr_accessible :security_users_role` within security_users_roles_to_users.rb